# If X fills the frame more than Y, does that mean X is closer to me in real life?

Tags: zoom, perspective

I saw this flat earther guy using the optical zoom of his Nikon P900 to zoom into a stop sign 1000ft away, then zooming into the sun. The gentleman was able to get a greater portion of his frame filled with the sun than he could with the stop sign.

How is that possible?

Comment: This guy thinks the sun is closer than the stop sign? Where does he think he is? Heaven? What is his explanation for why planes don't get burnt up in flight? ... Re your question: What do you mean by "zoom in closer"? Are you talking about how much of the frame the subject fills, the distance position on the focusing ring, or something else?

Comment: I'm reminded of Father Ted. Cows: Small or far away? [YouTube link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MMiKyfd6hA0)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about optics and math and not about photography.

Comment: Maybe try https://skeptics.stackexchange.com?

Comment: @Tetsujin exactly my first thought too!

Answer (score 6):

What does *"zoom closer to the sun"* mean?

That he was able to make the sun appear larger in an image than the stop sign?

That's not because he is closer to the sun, it is because the sun is ≈865,000 miles wide, while the stop sign is roughly 0.00047 miles (30 inches) wide.

That makes the sun 1,826,880,000 times larger than the stop sign. So even though the sun is 93 million miles away, it occupies about one-half degree of arc in the sky as viewed from the surface of the Earth. Our thirty inch stop sign, on the other hand, may only be about one-twentieth of a mile away (269 feet, to be more exact) and cover the same one-half degree of arc to an observer. At 1,000 feet, a thirty inch wide stop sign is only about one-seventh degree of arc wide to an observer.

Incidentally, the Moon is, on average, 238,900 miles away from the Earth. Since it is 2,159 miles wide, it is also roughly one-half degree wide in the sky. The Sun and Moon appear to be roughly the same size in the sky because the sun is 400 times larger than the moon but also about 400 times further away. The distance variation in the moon's elliptical orbit around the Earth and in the Earth's slightly elliptical orbit around the Sun are why sometimes solar eclipses are anular (the Moon is slightly too small to cover the Sun's disc) and at other times they are Total (the Moon is *just* large enough to cover the Sun's disc as seen from the surface of the Earth).

Comment: Thank you for answering. I know it was off topic but i didnt know where else to ask. i kind of felt like it was all bogus. But What he was saying was when you use optical zoom (versus digital), the lenses are actually getting closer to the object as that object fills the frame. Thus, his theory is the sun is some sort of projection since its able to fill the frame. I guess his theory is it should stay small if it was actually far away when using an optical zoom. i dont know how cameras and photography work so sorry if im completely off topic.

Comment: @MichaelMiller if that was true, then the original Canon 24-70mm f/2.8 L USM would be impossible, as at 24mm, the front lens is closer to any object than at 70mm. Also, as someone who works with beamer projections on a day-by-day basis as a professional, I can tell you that projections do not defy school book physics.

Answer (score 5):

If A appears larger than B, this could mean two things:

- A is in fact larger
- A is less distant

A way to determine the relationship of distances between things that can be done by laymen is to use parallax: Move one metre in any orthogonal direction and watch by how much the apparent position of A and B change. If A's position changes by a larger amount, then A will be closer - and vice versa.

[image: GIF animation]

<sup>Quick animation out of Maya. Height above ground (cam + torus + helix): 100cm, Torus diameter: ~30cm, helix height: ~95cm. Torus 1m away, helix 10m away. First: camera focal length 50mm, moving from X -25cm to X +25cm. Then changes to focal length 600mm and changes Z from 0m to -10m. Then it moves from X +25cm to X -25cm. Then focal length is changed to 24mm and Z is back to 0m, then helix is moved to the same Z-coordinate as the torus, then camera is moved to bird's view.</sup>

See how in the GIF, changing the focal length from 50mm to 600mm (and changing the relative distance to 7 and 1.6 times, respectively) does not eliminate parallax, but only makes it a bit harder to spot (at the same degree of orthogonal motion)? I could not, without knowing, tell you the exact distance - I can, however, state with absolute certainty that the helix is still behind the torus.

[Wikipedia's article on angular diameter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_diameter) also has some formulae and photos that should make the point of apparent vs. actual size clear.

---

"Zooming in", as in increasing the focal length, does not do anything. For example <sup>(not calculated examples, just to make the point)</sup> I can make a picture of a person's face at 24mm and a distance of roughly 50cm - or make "the same" <sup>As in: the head fills the same portion of the frame</sup> shot at 100mm and a distance of roughly 2m.

If I use 100mm and make a picture of a stop sign (0.4 m diameter) and the sun (1 392 684 000 m diameter) and both appear roughly the same size, then it simply means that the stop sign is much, much closer than the sun. Still, if it appears smaller, it still will be much closer to me, as we already pointed out that the stop sign's diameter is not the same as that of the sun.

Comment: **Off-topic:** Want more proof on the stupidity of flat-earthers' claims? Then you might like the [Testing Flattards](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLmWeueTF8l82GItQhl7vTP_WM43B4ebNq) and [Testing Geocentrism](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wyRJZbNmC7U&list=PLmWeueTF8l82THrHwihtcmhQdjcBQBXjT) videos.

Comment: Have you seen the guy who is trying to build his own rocket so he can go up and photograph the earth (to prove it's flat)? Ahahahaha bless his heart.

Comment: @Hueco Well, at least he seems to do something close to research - not like those "south pole can't be reached, because I say so"-morons.